# Hibernate dynamic operator string

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Is there a way to use an operator in Hibernate, that you don't know the type of ahead of time? Here's a bit of example code for context, showing how I'd like it to work:

```
s.createQuery("select from :table where column :op :value");
```

That doesn't work, so I wrote this `switch` logic:

```
public List<Model> findByProperty(final String propertyName,
                                  final String operator,
                                  final String value) {
  final Session s = getSession();
  Criteria criteria = s.createCriteria(Foo.class);
  // How could I dynamically use the type of operator
  // through Hibernate without perhaps a switch on operator

  switch (operator) {
    case '=':
      criteria = criteria.add(Expression.eq(propertyName, value);
    // ...
  }

  return criteria.list();
}
```

That works, but is there any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far?  what were the outcomes of your trials?  the general problem area you are talking about is called *reflection*; what do the Hibernate documents say about reflection?  and is there some particular thing in those docs you don't understand?  help us help you, by focusing / narrowing the question a bit

Comment: Well seeing as there's no way to use CreateCriteria to replace operators, I will probably be going with the switch approach I listed above.

I attempted to do something like `s.createQuery("select from :table where column :op :value");` and had trouble there, so image I will need to go with the `switch` statement route. Have you had any experience with this kind of thing?

Comment: I don't have a lot of Hibernate experience, no; my comment was a general suggestion for asking questions on SO; the `s.createQuery(...)` detail you included in your comment, for example, helps clarify your question a whole lot;  now I see better what you are trying to do, and seeing that, I'm now thinking that reflection won't help at all, as that applies to types, not operators; I recommend including that right in your question; I'll post a suggested edit to show what I mean, which you can accept or reject as you see fit;  HTH